Azure Service Bus message sometimes take long time to recieve
I have an application where there is one part WebApi (which as you can tell by the name is a webapi app service) and another part Worker (which is an Azure Function). They communicate with each other using Azure Service Bus. The WebApi service calls the Worker - the Started message, and the Worker calls back the WebApi - the Finished message. Everything works quite fine and as it should. The messages don't run extremely often. Mostly once an hour and they don't even run over each other.
However, once a day, typically at 06:00 am, the messages take an extremely long time to send. Roughly 1-2 minutes. Then because of this the state machine also malfunctions ) in my opinion some message expires. Otherwise messages are processed in seconds. For a while I thought it was due to cold start. But the message goes slowly to Worker and to WebApi. I'm getting desperate about this because I can't find any more info. These logs are info from the consumer method. Where there is no other code before the log.


I don't see any errors in the log. The only thing in the log is the occasional message. Which is a known problem and quite annoying

Result: Cancelled
Exception: Grpc.Core.RpcException: Status(StatusCode="Cancelled", Detail="Call canceled by the client.", DebugException="System.OperationCanceledException: The operation was canceled.")
---> System.OperationCanceledException: The operation was canceled.
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.ServiceBusMessageActions.CompleteMessageAsync(ServiceBusReceivedMessage message, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in D:\a_work\1\s\extensions\Worker.Extensions.ServiceBus\src\ServiceBusMessageActions.cs:line 78
at Worker.FunctionApp.DefaultServiceBusFunction.AsTopicResultWithCompleteMessage[TConsumer](ServiceBusReceivedMessage message, ServiceBusMessageActions messageActions, String topic, String subs, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in D:\a\1\s\Src\Worker.FunctionApp\DefaultServiceBusFunction.cs:line 50
at Worker.FunctionApp.Started.Run(ServiceBusReceivedMessage message, ServiceBusMessageActions messageActions, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in D:\a\1\s\Src\Worker.FunctionApp\Started.cs:line 24
at Worker.FunctionApp.DirectFunctionExecutor.ExecuteAsync(FunctionContext context) in D:\a\1\s\Src\Worker.FunctionApp\obj\Release\net8.0\Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk.Generators\Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk.Generators.FunctionExecutorGenerator\GeneratedFunctionExecutor.g.cs:line 39
at Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.OutputBindings.OutputBindingsMiddleware.Invoke(FunctionContext context, FunctionExecutionDelegate next) in D:\a_work\1\s\src\DotNetWorker.Core\OutputBindings\OutputBindingsMiddleware.cs:line 13
at Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.FunctionsApplication.InvokeFunctionAsync(FunctionContext context) in D:\a_work\1\s\src\DotNetWorker.Core\FunctionsApplication.cs:line 91
at Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Handlers.InvocationHandler.InvokeAsync(InvocationRequest request) in D:\a_work\1\s\src\DotNetWorker.Grpc\Handlers\InvocationHandler.cs:line 88
Stack: at Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.ServiceBusMessageActions.CompleteMessageAsync(ServiceBusReceivedMessage message, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in D:\a_work\1\s\extensions\Worker.Extensions.ServiceBus\src\ServiceBusMessageActions.cs:line 78
at Worker.FunctionApp.DefaultServiceBusFunction.AsTopicResultWithCompleteMessage[TConsumer](ServiceBusReceivedMessage message, ServiceBusMessageActions messageActions, String topic, String subs, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in D:\a\1\s\Src\Worker.FunctionApp\DefaultServiceBusFunction.cs:line 50
at Worker.FunctionApp.Started.Run(ServiceBusReceivedMessage message, ServiceBusMessageActions messageActions, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in D:\a\1\s\Src\Worker.FunctionApp\Started.cs:line 24
at Worker.FunctionApp.DirectFunctionExecutor.ExecuteAsync(FunctionContext context) in D:\a\1\s\Src\Worker.FunctionApp\obj\Release\net8.0\Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk.Generators\Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk.Generators.FunctionExecutorGenerator\GeneratedFunctionExecutor.g.cs:line 39
at Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.OutputBindings.OutputBindingsMiddleware.Invoke(FunctionContext context, FunctionExecutionDelegate next) in D:\a_work\1\s\src\DotNetWorker.Core\OutputBindings\OutputBindingsMiddleware.cs:line 13
at Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.FunctionsApplication.InvokeFunctionAsync(FunctionContext context) in D:\a_work\1\s\src\DotNetWorker.Core\FunctionsApplication.cs:line 91
at Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Handlers.InvocationHandler.InvokeAsync(InvocationRequest request) in D:\a_work\1\s\src\DotNetWorker.Grpc\Handlers\InvocationHandler.cs:line 88

Thank you
EDIT:
I use MassTransit in WebApi and Worker also.
WebApi:
services.AddMassTransit(o =>
{
    o.AddConsumers(Assembly.Load("Messaging"));

    o.AddSagaStateMachine<RunDataStateMachine, RunDataState>()
        .InMemoryRepository();

    o.UsingAzureServiceBus(async (context, cfg) =>
    {
        cfg.Host(new HostSettings
        {
            ServiceUri = new Uri("sb://´.."),
            TokenCredential = new DefaultAzureCredential()
        });

        cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(formatter.Saga<RunDataState>(), e =>
        {
            e.ConfigureSaga<RunDataState>(context);
        });

        cfg.SubscriptionEndpoint<Started>(formatter.Consumer<StartedConsumer>(), e =>
        {
            e.ConfigureConsumer<StartedConsumer>(context);
        });

        // Calculate report
        await CreateOrUpdateTopicWithSubs(adminClient, formatter.MessageName<Finished>(), formatterWorker.ConsumerFromMessageName<finished>());
    });
});

Worker:
    services.AddMassTransitForAzureFunctions(cfg =>
    {
        cfg.AddConsumers(Assembly.Load("Messaging"));

    }, "ServiceBusConnection", (context, configuration) =>
    {
        var settings = new HostSettings
        {
            ServiceUri = new Uri("sb://...."),
            TokenCredential = new DefaultAzureCredential(),
        };

        configuration.Host(settings);
    });

host.json
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "logLevel": {
      "Default": "Trace",
      "System": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Information"
    },
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request;Exception",
        "maxTelemetryItemsPerSecond": 20
      },
      "enableLiveMetricsFilters": true,
      "logLevel": {
        "Default": "Information"
      }
    }
  },
  "extensions": {
    "serviceBus": {
      "prefetchCount": 32,
      "messageHandlerOptions": {
        "autoComplete": false,
        "maxConcurrentCalls": 32,
        "maxAutoRenewDuration": "00:30:00"
      }
    },
    "eventHub": {
      "maxBatchSize": 64,
      "prefetchCount": 256,
      "batchCheckpointFrequency": 1
    }
  }
}

StartedFunction:
public class StartedFunction : DefaultServiceBusFunction
{
    public StartedFunction(IMessageReceiver receiver) : base(receiver)
    {
    }

    [Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Function(nameof(StartedFunction))]
    public async Task Run([Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.ServiceBusTrigger(_topicName, _subscriptionName, Connection = _connection)] ServiceBusReceivedMessage message,
        ServiceBusMessageActions messageActions, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        await AsTopicResultWithCompleteMessage<Consumer>(message, messageActions, _topicName, _subscriptionName, cancellationToken);
    }
}

DefaultServiceBusFunction:
public abstract class DefaultServiceBusFunction
{
    private readonly IMessageReceiver _receiver;
    public bool IsComplete { get; private set; } = false;

    public DefaultServiceBusFunction(IMessageReceiver receiver)
    {
        _receiver = receiver;
    }

    public async Task AsTopicResultWithCompleteMessage<TConsumer>(ServiceBusReceivedMessage message, ServiceBusMessageActions messageActions, string topic, string subs, CancellationToken cancellationToken) where TConsumer : class, IConsumer
    {
        try
        {
            await _receiver.HandleConsumer<TConsumer>(topic, subs, message, cancellationToken);
            if (!IsComplete)
            {
                await messageActions.CompleteMessageAsync(message, cancellationToken);
                IsComplete = true;
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            if (!IsComplete)
            {
                await messageActions.CompleteMessageAsync(message, cancellationToken);
                IsComplete = true;
            }
            throw;
        }
    }
}


Is the Azure Function using the consumption plan?

@RuiJarimba Yes

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1470326/how-often-will-azure-function-consumpltion-plan-pu

And what exactly is there to help me? There is no extra information in the article. It just explains what "wakes up" the Azure function.

A cold start would not impact the time it takes to send a message over ASB. I suspect, besides cold start, there's something else going on @rui-jarimba. It would help to share the code how your function is set up to send a message. Are you instantiating the SDK client or using the output binding, etc.

@SeanFeldman i edit my question

Just looking to get some clarification. If I'm reading the stack trace correctly, then the problem isn't occurring with starting to process the Service Bus message... Rather, it's when your code is calling messageActions.CompleteMessageAsync which is actually after you've processed the message content. Is that your understanding too?

@AndrewB I may have clumsily conflated two things here. What bothers me now is that it can take 1-2 minutes to send a message. It doesn't throw an exception for anything. And the other thing that may or may not be related is this particular error, but it occurs in different ways.

Ah OK, I see. Is this the task inbetween "WebApi started" and "WebApi finished", taking around 3 minutes, that you want help with then?

@AndrewB Yes, that's exactly

Might need to see a bit more code perhaps, to understand the flow better. For example, could you show the lines that write the log messages for Worker - Started - started etc. I confess I'm perhaps understandably getting confused between Started (the message) and started (the worker status) :-)
